# Blank screen on Keynote presentation play?

Tags: iwork-keynote

On a RMBP running Yosemite, Keynote updated to the latest version on the App Store.

On opening a keynote presentation created and run successfully months ago, when I play it, I get only a blank screen. If I hit the space bar a few times and hit ESC, the presentations appears to have been moved up that many slides, but nothing shows on my laptop.

I don't have any external screens attached, so while I suspect something thinks there's an another screen and is trying to project to it, I can't fix it.

I've tried rebooting, no luck... any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keynote takes over complete control of the graphics system (as does Powerpoint) so that presenter screen and primary screens can be used if needed. Therefore when Keynote is in play the other screen displays Presenter screen or is black if presenter screen is switched off in Keynote preferences.